# Regex wildcard to only match strings which don't have an underscore

Tags: .net, regex

I've got a series of strings in this format:

```
Something_fromSomewhere
Something_fromSomewhere_ABC123
Something_fromSomewhere_DEF456
Something_fromSomewhereElse
Something_fromSomewhereElse_GHI123
```

I'm attempting to group them like this...

```
Something_fromSomewhere
    Something_fromSomewhere_ABC123
    Something_fromSomewhere_DEF456

Something_fromSomewhereElse
    Something_fromSomewhereElse_GHI123
```

So I want to pick out strings which contain this pattern:

```
^[Any1]_from[Any2]$
```

But I only want to pick out rows where `Any2` doesn't contain any underscores. How can I do this?

(Once I've got the 'root' elements, I can do simple string matching to find the children.)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern won't do what you think it does. It will match a single `A`, `n`, `y` or `1` character, followed by a literal `_from`, followed by a single `A`, `n`, `y` or `2` character. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around your string will also ensure the *entire* string must match the pattern, and not just a substring.

Perhaps you want a pattern like this:

```
^(.*)_from([^_]*)
```

This will match zero or more of any character, captured in group 1, followed by a literal `_from`, followed by zero or more of any character other than underscores, captured in group 2. It will also allow any other characters to follow the matched substring.

Or possibly this:

```
^([^_]*)_from([^_]*)
```

This will match zero or more of any character other than underscores, captured in group 1, followed by a literal `_from`, followed by zero or more of any character other than underscores, captured in group 2. It will also allow any other characters to follow the matched substring.

Answer (score 0):

The way to specify a non-empty sequence of characters other than an underscore is

```
[^_]+
```

When you put a `^` symbol inside a character class (that's the fancy name for a set of characters which could be defined through the square bracket syntax) the character class gets inverted: it matches everything *not* included in the class, rather than matching what is included.

In your case, the overall expression would look like this:

```
^[^_]+_from[^_]+$
```